# A question about specific GNU Makefile entry

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu

I am trying to make sense of the following lines in a GNU Makefile (modified to obscure proprietary stuff):

```
KERNEL_SEARCH := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build  \
     /usr/src/linux-headers-$(shell uname -r) \
     /usr/src/linux
     
      temp_dir = $(shell [ -e $(dir)/include/linux ] && echo $(dir))
      KERNEL_SEARCH := $(foreach dir, $(K_SEARCH), $(temp_dir))
```

My understanding is that in the first line, `KERNEL_SEARCH` is successively assigned each of the paths separated by `\`. However, I am not sure what do the subsequent lines do? Can someone provide a quick explanation?

TIA

Vinod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the Make variable `dir` has been given a value, say `/usr/src/linux`. Now consider:

```
temp_dir = $(shell [ -e $(dir)/include/linux ] && echo $(dir))
```

This is a Make statement that constructs the line

```
[ -e /usr/src/linux/include/linux ] && echo /usr/src/linux
```

then passes it to the shell, then stores the result in the variable `temp_dir`.

The fist part, in the brackets, is a shell conditional, which tests the existence of that file. The second part is a simple `echo` statement which prints something to the screen. The `&&` in the middle is a boolean `AND`; if the first part evaluates as False, then evaluation stops, but if the first part evaluates as True, then the shell proceeds to the second part. So if the `dir` contains `include/linux`, then the shell will print the `dir`, otherwise it will do nothing.

So if the directory named by `dir` contains `include/linux`, then `temp_dir` will contain the value of `dir`, otherwise `temp_dir` will wind up empty.

Now consider:

```
KERNEL_SEARCH := ...
```

The variable `KERNEL_SEARCH` contains a list. It is **not** successively assigned various things, it's just a list, a long string with some spaces in it. (I'd show you what it looks like, but that depends on the shell, and it would be kind of cryptic.) Those backslashes (`\`) are there just to allow wrapping of the long line, to make the makefile easier to read.

Now the last line:

```
KERNEL_SEARCH := $(foreach dir, $(K_SEARCH), $(temp_dir))
```

I *strongly* suspect that you got the variable names swapped when you were obfuscating the code. I'll swap them back:

```
K_SEARCH := $(foreach dir, $(KERNEL_SEARCH), $(temp_dir))
```

[The `foreach` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function) takes three arguments. Roughly, the first is a variable name, the second is a list, and the third is something to be expanded. Make iterates over the list, and for each word in the list it assigns that word to the variable, and expands the third argument. In this case, for each directory in `$(KERNEL_SEARCH)`, Make expands `$(temp_dir)` and gets either the name of the directory, or nothing.

So the result is a list of those directories (from the original list) which contain `include/linux`.